# Moving back through a table of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (It's actually a view, but hopefully it works the same) with data that holds all calendar dates, and a flag to say if that day is a day that we do scheduled payment runs. This dataset is generated based on some rules, but is out of the scope of the question at hand. The rule is that we run payments once per week (But this can change to ever 2 weeks etc), The result set displayed below say that we run payments on every Friday (Ever 7 days). The columns are the actual date, a flag showing if it's a payment day, and a flag showing if it's some form of holiday date.

```
CREATE TABLE Schedule
(
    DateValue DATE NOT NULL,
    IsPaymentDay BIT NOT NULL,
    IsHoliday BIT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-01', 0, 1)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-02', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-03', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-04', 1, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-05', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-06', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-07', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-08', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-09', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-10', 0, 1)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-11', 1, 1)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-12', 0, 1)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-13', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-14', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-15', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-16', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-17', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-17', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-18', 1, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-19', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('2013-01-20', 0, 0)

SELECT * FROM Schedule

DROP TABLE Schedule
```

You can run this code to create the data.

Now, I need to cover a last business rule. That is, if a payment run falls on a public holiday, or a day on which the office isn't staffed (The Christmas period, for example), the system must do the payment run on the day before the place shuts down, or the day before the holiday.

So, in the example below, the first payment run of the year is Friday the 4th of Jan. That one is OK. It will go off as planned.

The next payment, however, goes off on the 11th of Jan... But that's a 'public holiday' and the office is shut. In fact, it was closed from the 10th, and only re-opens on the 13th. So, in this example, we need to process the payment run on the 9th.

What I need to to have a few functions. One, that answers the question, "Is today a payment run day?". Easily accomplished:

```
SELECT *
FROM Schedule WHERE DateValue = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
AND IsPaymentDay = 1
```

This returns a row if this is a payment day.

However, I need to take into account the fact that the office might be closed. So, I'd need to say:

```
SELECT *
FROM Schedule WHERE DateValue = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
AND IsPaymentDay = 1 
AND IsHoliday = 0
```

This would say if the day is going to be OK as a payment day. However, now I am stuck. If I run this on the last day the office is open, and there is a payment within the 'shut down' period that proceeds today, then it should return a TRUE result for the question.

So, when I run it for the 9th, it should indicate that the 9th IS a payment day, because there's a holiday period which will stop a payment day from firing.

A few idea I have, but not sure I can get them to work, is:

Call the function that checks if a date is a payment date... process the payments, depending on the result... then call a function which gets the next payment date. If that date falls on a holiday day, select all the dates between then and now, and cursor back through them, until I find the first available payment date. If that date is today, the process.

But, it seems messy. Hopeing someone can help me do this neatly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT *
FROM Schedule 
WHERE (DateDiff(dd,GETDATE(),DateValue) = 0 AND IsPaymentDay = 1 AND IsHoliday = 0)
    OR ( DateDiff(dd,GETDATE(),DateValue) = 0 AND IsPaymentDay = 0 AND IsHoliday = 0 AND
         EXISTS( 
         SELECT *
         FROM Schedule holiday
         WHERE DateDiff(dd,GETDATE(),DateValue) BETWEEN 1 AND 6 AND IsPaymentDay = 1 AND IsHoliday = 1
               AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                               FROM Schedule
                               WHERE DateDiff(dd,GETDATE(),Schedule.DateValue) >= 1 AND DateDiff(dd,Schedule.DateValue,holiday.DateValue)>=1
                                     AND Schedule.IsHoliday = 0 AND Schedule.IsPaymentDay=0)
         )
    )
```

Here I check for the next 7 days (`BETWEEN 1 AND 6`). You can teak this value according to your requirements. If you need to check for all records from today, just change it to `>=1`. Like this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM Schedule 
    WHERE (DateDiff(dd,GETDATE(),DateValue) = 0 AND IsPaymentDay = 1 AND IsHoliday = 0)
        OR ( DateDiff(dd,GETDATE(),DateValue) = 0 AND IsPaymentDay = 0 AND IsHoliday = 0 AND
             EXISTS( 
             SELECT *
             FROM Schedule holiday
             WHERE DateDiff(dd,GETDATE(),DateValue) >=1 AND IsPaymentDay = 1 AND IsHoliday = 1
                   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                   FROM Schedule
                                   WHERE DateDiff(dd,GETDATE(),Schedule.DateValue) >= 1 AND DateDiff(dd,Schedule.DateValue,holiday.DateValue)>=1
                                         AND Schedule.IsHoliday = 0 AND Schedule.IsPaymentDay=0)
             )
        )
```

Comment: Thanks! The result set is always empty... Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Craig: did you replace GetDate() with the date you need to test? I replaced it with 2013-01-04, 2013-01-09,2013-01-10,2013-01-11 in 4 different tests and it returned the correct row.

Comment: Sorry @Khanh! I didn't. Added a '@DateToTest' variable, replaced the GetDates and hey preto! Wow! Thanks! That seems to work perfectly. I'm going to test it now... but that seems like it did the trick! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can even achive this in SQL statement as well -

```
SELECT *
  FROM Schedule S1
 WHERE Datevalue = CAST(Getdate() AS DATE)
   AND Datevalue =
       (SELECT MAX(Datevalue)
          FROM Schedule S2
         WHERE Datevalue <= (SELECT MIN(Datevalue)
                               FROM Schedule S3
                              WHERE Datevalue >= S1.Datevalue
                                AND Ispaymentday = 1)
           AND Isholiday = 0);
```

**Edit**

to see the all paymentday you can remove the `gatdate` value -

```
 SELECT *
     FROM Schedule S1
     WHERE Datevalue =
           (SELECT MAX(Datevalue)
              FROM Schedule S2
             WHERE Datevalue <= (SELECT MIN(Datevalue)
                                   FROM Schedule S3
                                  WHERE Datevalue >= S1.Datevalue
                                    AND Ispaymentday = 1)
               AND Isholiday = 0);
```

Comment: I am getting no results back. Will try work this out, thanks.

Comment: @Craig May be because your system date is not paymentday.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
 create Function IsPaymentDate (@date Date) returns int
 as
 begin

     declare @IsPaymentDate int

     select @IsPaymentDate = 
            case DateDiff(dd, max(a.Datevalue), @date)
                 when 0 then 1
                 else 0
            end
     from Schedule a
     where a.Isholiday = 0 and 
           a.Datevalue <= (select min(b.Datevalue) from Schedule b
                          where b.Datevalue >= @date and b.Ispaymentday = 1)         

     return @IsPaymentDate

 end
```